# IBM Model M keyboard not detected on cold boot?

Tags: keyboard, ps2, ibm-ps2

Sharing some experience for the clicky keyboards fans, hope it can be useful so somebody...

A few months ago I got my first mechanical keyboard : an old IBM Model M, that I found in an electronic trash container at my work :)

I had been remotely interested in mechanical keyboards before, reading stuf and so on, but hadn't ever actually used one. I instantly loved the feel of it, the heaviness and strudiness, but above all the tactile (and auditory) feedback of the buckling-spring keys.

So I took the keyboard home, cleaned it thoroughly and plugged it into my PC, which luckily still has a PS/2 port. I was quite disappointed to find out that the keyboard wasn't detected on a cold boot. However it worked after a reboot, or when exiting from sleep or hibernate. It didn't work in the BIOS or in the OS either.

My motherboard is an Asus Ivy Bridge generation motherboard with an Intel chipset, but some research on the web showed me the problem can happen with other models too.

How to avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be on an electronic level, with the motherboard unable to supply enough power to the keyboard on a cold boot.

The work-around I found was the following:

In the BIOS (well actually UEFI) enable the option called **power on PS/2**, or **wake on PS/2** or something similar.

This seems to make the motherboard keep the keyboard powered even when the PC is shut down. Then you can start the PC by pressing a key, and in any case the keyboard works directly after booting, no need to reboot.

Let me know if you encounter the same problem and if this solution works for you.